# : Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, ambiguous, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

I am handling exceptions for `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class` and
`MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class`

I am using `@ExceptionHandler` annotation in `@ControllerAdvice` Class but when I try to use handle both exceptions and write two separate method for them, it throws the above error and also say caused by Ambiguous. I checked for ambiguity but two methods are totally different.

```
package com.crud.exceptionHandler;

import java.lang.annotation.Repeatable;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;


@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandling extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(IdNotFoundException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> IdNotFoundException(IdNotFoundException ex) 
  {
      ErrorMessage exceptionResponse=new ErrorMessage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getReasonPhrase(),ex.getMessage());
      return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(exceptionResponse,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

  }
  
  
  @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex)
{
    String message = 
              " Http Method request should be of type " + ex.getSupportedHttpMethods();
      ErrorMessage exceptionResponse=new ErrorMessage(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.getReasonPhrase(),message);
    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(exceptionResponse,HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);

}
  

  @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatchException(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex) 
  {
      String message = 
              ex.getName() + " should be of type " + ex.getRequiredType().getName();
      ErrorMessage exceptionResponse=new ErrorMessage(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase(),message);
      return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(exceptionResponse,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

  }
  

}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'basicErrorController' method 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
to { [/error]}: There is already 'userController' bean method
com.crud.controller.UserController#handleErrorForInvalidURL() mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.crud.CrudApplication.main(CrudApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'basicErrorController' method 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
to { [/error]}: There is already 'userController' bean method
com.crud.controller.UserController#handleErrorForInvalidURL() mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.validateMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:665) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:631) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:328) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:395) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:76) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$2(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:298) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:723) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:296) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:265) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:224) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:212) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:206) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Remove `@RestController` from your advice. It isn't a controller it is an advice. Also could you please add the conflicting method?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I removed the @RestController .
still getting the same error.
dont understand why is it saying ambiguity for "argument mismatch" and "http method request"  exceptions.

Comment: Spring Boot has a default error handler which will handle errors already, you probably decided you need a method in your `UserController` to handle errors as well and that one is conflicting with the default one. My suspicion is that your `UserController` is also double annotation with `@RestController` and `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: No,UserController is all okay. there is not much code.
but there is one silly doubt i wanted to ask :
I wrote some error handling method code in user controller class but then I deleted the whole class and created one.
is there such a thing that deleted action is not updated and still haunting me.
is there any way to update project

Comment: If you didn't clean but just build the old class might linger around.

Comment: Gooood News.
finally its working and here is the answer:
as I was extending the class responseEntityExceptionhandler, this class has already wriiten the exception for HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class with method name handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.
so ypu need to @override that same method in your class.
somehow i was facing problems to override but I managed it by creating new class that wont be extending any classes so no need to override and freely do whatever it want.
defined my method there with @Exceptionhandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)